# Rudin's proof of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem (7.25 Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis

[image][image]In part (b), Rudin claims that there are finitely many points $x_1,\ldots ,x_m$ in $\color{red}{E}$ such that

$$K\subset V(x_1,\delta)\cup\cdots\cup V(x_m,\delta).$$

I have no idea why Rudin can pick these points in $\color{red}{E}$ instead of $\color{green}{K}$. After all, it's $\color{green}{K}$ that presents compactness.

Indeed, before doing that, Rudin reminds me of denseness possessed by $\color{red}{E}$. But what next? Can somebody tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y_1,...,y_m\in K$ such that $K\subset V(y_1,{\delta\over 4}),...,V(y_m,{\delta\over 4})$. Since $E$ is dense, there exists an element $x_i$ of $E$ in $V(y_i,{\delta\over 4})$, $V(y_1,{\delta\over 4})\subset V(x_i,\delta)$.

Comment: I appreciate your kindly help. It's very straightforward.